# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: on Jersey Rest Webservice call after upgrading Weblogic to 12c (12.1.3.0.0)

Tags: java, rest, weblogic, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

A part of our application which calls a REST webservice using Jersey Client 2.15 stopped working after we upgraded our Weblogic to Weblogic 12C - 12.1.3.0.0.

The exception trace we were getting was:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.<init>(JerseyWebTarget.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(JerseyClient.java:185)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(JerseyClient.java:70)
```

We were sure that it was a `javax.ws.rs` mismatch between Jersey and Weblogic WS libraries.

**Dependencies**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.15</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.15</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.connectors</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-apache-connector</artifactId>
    <version>2.15</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not longer did we realize that following our application logs with the above stack trace was misleading. So we started looking into Weblogic logs. The domain log did in fact gave as a totally different stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocatorFactory.create(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/extension/ServiceLocatorGenerator;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocatorFactory$CreatePolicy;)Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator;
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Injections.java:138)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Injections.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl.<init>(RuntimeDelegateImpl.java:63)
    at
```

So after some firefighting and playing around with `weblogic.xml` and package overrides the issue was sorted. The following were the final package overrides which actually did solve the problem:

```
    <wls:package-name>com.sun.jersey.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>org.glassfish.jersey.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>org.glassfish.hk2.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>org.jvnet.hk2.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>org.objectweb.asm.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>com.sun.ws.rs.ext.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>javax.ws.rs.*</wls:package-name>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution. I'm encountering a similar problem to deploy a newer version of jersey on Weblogic 12.1.3. Could you post your whole weblogic.xml configuration?